# Using Surv function repeatedly with different data frames

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm running some Surv() functions, and one thing I do not like, or understand, is why this function does not take a "data=" argument. This is annoying because I want to perform the same Surv() function on the same data frame but filtered by different criteria each time.

So for example, my data frame is called "ikt" and I want to filter by "donor_type2=='LD'" and also use a strata variable "plan 2". I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
library(survival)
library(dplyr)

ikt<-data.frame(organ_yrs=(seq(1,20)),
           organ_status=rep(c(0,0,1,1),each=5),
           plan2=rep(c('A','B','A','B'),each=5),
           donor_type2=rep(c('LD','DD'),each=10) )

organ_surv_func<-function(data,criteria,strata) {
data2<-filter(data,criteria)
Surv(data2$organ_yrs,data2$organ_status)~data2$strata
}

organ_surv_func(ikt,donor_type2=='LD',plan2)

Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : object 'donor_type2' not found
```

I'm coming from a SAS background so that's probably why I'm thinking this should work and it doesn't...

I looked up something about sapply(), but I don't think that works when the function doesn't have the data= option.

Also the reason I need the Surv() object and not just survfit(Surv()) (which would let me use data=) is because I'm also using survdiff() for log-rank tests, which takes in the Surv() object as it's main argument:

```
lr<-function (surv) {
round(1-pchisq(survdiff(surv)$chisq,length(survfit(surv)$strata)-1),3)
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Be clear where the `Surv()` function is coming from (that is not a base R function).

Comment: okay I added that in

Comment: `Surv()` is usually used in in formulas to describe relationships between variables. It doesn't usually come along with data. How exactly are you trying to use this with `survdiff`? But really your current problem (error message) is about how you are trying to pass parameters to your `dplyr` function. Check out the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html). SAS is very different from R. SAS is more of a MACRO language but R requires proper functional programming techniques.

Comment: survdiff() takes in Surv(), and I'm using that as part of a function to generate the log-rank p-values. see above

Comment: According to the docs, `survdiff` takes a formula and it has a `data=` parameter. You should not be passing a the result of `Surv()` directly to `survdiff()` Maybe check out the help page. (Note the `~` in all the examples which indicate a formula.)

Comment: Ah I see, I can just add the data argument to survdiff within my function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this "answer" to caution you against proceeding down the path you seem to be following. The `Surv` function is really intended to be used as the LHS of a formula defined within one of the survival package functions. You should avoid using constructions like:

```
Surv(data2$organ_yrs,data2$organ_status)~data2$strata
```

For one thing it's needlessly verbose, but more importantly, it will prevent the use of `predict` when it comes time to match up names to formals. The `survdiff` and the other survival functions all have both a "data" argument as well as a "subset" argument. The subset function should allow you to avoid using `filter`.

```
 organ_surv_func<-function(data, covar) {
      form = as.formula(substitute( Surv(organ_yrs, organ_status) ~ covar, list(covar=covar) ) )
      survdiff(form, data=data)
}
# although I think running surdiff in a for-loop might be easier,
# as it would involve fewer tricky language constructs
organ_surv_func(  subset(ikt, (donor_type2=='LD')), covar=quote(plan2))
```

If you assign the output of `survfit` to a named variable, you will be able to more economically access `chisq` and `strata`:

```
myfit <- organ_surv_func(  subset(ikt, (donor_type2=='LD')), covar=quote(plan2))
my.lr.test<-function (myfit) {
                round(1-pchisq(myfit$chisq, length(myfit$strata)-1), 3)
                              }
my.lr.test(myfit) # not going to be useful with that dataset.
```

Comment: thanks, is there a reason subset is preferred to filter?

Comment: For me it’s familiarity with ‘subset’ and not with ‘filter’.